# Selection rules in Stark Effect using parity in particular

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

In the context of the Stark effect as analyzed by perturbation theory with an electric field in the z-direction, we have to examine the matrix element
$$\langle n',l',m'|z|n,l,m \rangle.$$

From angular momentum considerations (Wigner-Eckart theorem) we are able to deduce that non-vanishing elements occur only if $l-l'=\pm1,0$ and $m'-m = \pm 1,0$. Using parity, we are able to further exlude the $l-l'=0$ case. According to Sakurai (3rd edition) equation 5.65, it seems that we are able to also exclude $m'-m = \pm 1$. How do we exclude this on the basis of parity and angular momentum considerations alone (Sakurai does not use $[z,L_z]=0$ in this conclusion)? Is this an erratum in Sakurai?

Edit: Per the first comment, I attach a picture of the full page from Sakurai for reference. It seems to me that using $L_z$ to determine the m-selection rule is stated as a distinct strategy.

[image]

Comment: I only have the second edition, but he uses $[z,L_z]$ in his Wigner-Eckhart theorem by applying it to the $m=0$ component of the vector operator. He further makes it explicit in the subsequent chapter.

Comment: @lpz Please see my edit when you can.

Comment: Thanks, the passage was the same though. The fact that $[T^{(1)}_0,L_z]=0$ is used in the Wigner-Eckhart theorem so even the first proof uses $[z,L_z]=0$ indirectly. The second approach makes the connection more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have misinterpreted the Wigner-Eckhart selection rules.

The expression $$<n',l',m'|T^{(k)}_q|n,l,m>$$ must obey $m' = q + m$ and $|l-k| \leq l' \leq |l+k|$ (see 3.11.28 and 3.11.32 in Sakurai 2nd edition, or 3.471 and 3.471 in Sakurai 3rd edition).

$z$ behaves as a $T^{(k=1)}_{q=0}$ tensor operator, according to either equation 3.11.16 in 2nd edition or 3.459 in 3rd edition, which means that our selection rules simplify to $m' = 0 + m = m$ and $|l-1| \leq l' \leq |l+1|$.

All this comes down to Sakurai actually overshooting the requirements. The Wigner-Eckhart theorem alone is sufficient to prove 5.65 in the picture which you attached.

Parity just gives a redundant condition that $l' + 1 + l$ must be even, which is already enforced by the $|l-1| \leq l' \leq |l+1|$ selection rule.